# try use data from json file with php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get my data from a json file with php

```
<?php

$url = 'path/to/my/file.json';
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$characters = json_decode($data);
echo $characters[0]->name;
?>
```

I got the message

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

when I do the echo.

Somebody can help me with this?

file.json

```
[
 {
    "name": "Aragorn",
    "race": "Human"
 }, 
 {
    "name": "Legolas",
    "race": "Elf"
 },
 {
    "name": "Gimli",
    "race": "Dwarf"
 }
]
```

Comment: Look closely at $data. The problem is there.

Comment: @akond when echo $data it looks ok.

Comment: what is it then?

Comment: @akond I don't know. this is why I post it here

Comment: What is the data?

Comment: do `print_r($characters);` and post it.

Comment: How does `$characters` look like? Just output it with `var_dump()` and share it with us.

Comment: @akond Edit the post so you can see the json file with the data

Comment: Tip: NEVER assume that a index number exists. First validate, then display.

Comment: @Marcel When do var_dump($characters)  it returns NULL

Comment: @msbir that means that json_decode couldn't decode the given data, most likely due to incorrect formatting. Use var_dump($data); instead. Update your question with the result.

Comment: So here we got the problem. When `$characters` is NULL you can 't access an array or something else. What happens, when you output `$data` the same way? Is it also null?

Comment: It looks like `$characters` is an array. Access array members using bracket notation. `$characters['name'].

Comment: @Naltroc, negative. OP commented that json_decode returned null, meaning the given data is not a valid json format.

Comment: @NiekvanderMaaden Missed that. In this case, the code in the question should be updated to remove the `[]` brackets in `file.json`.

Comment: Every thing is fine i think check this https://eval.in/785105

Comment: Yeah, it was not a valid json format. Thank you all!!

Comment: @msbir which php version you are using ? it's work fine with <5.6